# laravel model, adding attribute to model

Tags: laravel, eloquent, orm, laravel-8

I have a user model, and I want to add (an attribute to the user model) the user's email that it was before it was updated.

```
before@email.com
new@email.com
```

Within the user model, I have this function, I can get the before email, I was wondering I can assign some fake attribute, so I can access it like: $user->beforeEmail

```
protected static function booted()
{
    static::saved(function ($user) {
        $user->beforeEmail = $user->original['email'];
    });
}

$user->beforeEmail // before@email.com
```

The code above is not working but provided it to help illustrate what I am trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the email address has changed just before storing the new email to the db. This can be accomplished by using the `saving` event instead of the `saved` event.

```php
protected static function booted()
{
   static::saving(function ($user) {
       if($user->isDirty('email')){
            $user->beforeEmail = $user->email
       }
   });
}
```

Note: Your code example will not save the changes automatically since the `saved` event is ran after executing the query. It's possible that your code works just by adding `$user->save()`

Comment: ended up going the event/listener route. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to get this value in the model or in a different class? As what you have works with a few adjustments already.

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    static::saved(function($user){
        $user->originalEmail = $user->original['email'];
    }
}
```

You can access `originalEmail` if you update the model in a controller or other class, like so:

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->update([
          'email' => 'email@email.com'
       ]);
// $user, $user->originalEmail, $user->some_test_accessor all return the correct values
```

I've also tested with an accessor, just to verify and it still works as though the value is available in the model. I'm not sure where you're attempting to access this value, though.

```
public function getSomeTestAccessorAttribute(){
    return $this->originalEmail;
}
```

Does any of this help?

Comment: My apologizes, I failed to mention the originalEmail is not in the users table, I was trying to do some laravel automagic in hopes I could create a new attribute to the user model on the fly. Looks like I'll need to create some event and a listener.

Comment: went w/ event/listener route